# MySQL query to get list of latest updated pages, but only one result for every slug?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table for pages with fields `slug` (string, **not** unique) and `updated` (datetime). I want to retrieve a list of last updated pages based on the `updated` field, but I only want one result for every `slug` (since slugs can be re-used across pages in this case). What to do?

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages`
GROUP BY `slug`
ORDER BY `updated` DESC
```

That gives only one result per slug, but not always the last updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM pages p1
LEFT JOIN pages p2 ON p1.slug = p2.slug AND p1.updated < p2.updated
WHERE p2.updated IS NULL
ORDER BY p1.updated DESC
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html.

Answer (score 1):

This is MSSQL - but will return 'ties' if a page is updated 2 or more times at exactly the same datetime.

```
SELECT * FROM pages
WHERE Updated In
(
SELECT Max(Updated)
FROM pages
GROUP BY slug
)
```